# $0$ scalar multiplied by any vector gives $0$ vector

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory, vectors

I am confused about an elementary linear algebra proof of the fact that $0 \cdot x=0 \ \forall \  x$.

The proof goes something like, using $(a+b)\cdot x=a \cdot x+b \cdot x$ and substituting $b=0$, we have that for all $x \in V$,

\begin{align}
  (a+0)\cdot x&=a \cdot x+0 \cdot x\\
  \implies a\cdot x&=a \cdot x+0 \cdot x \  \forall \ a \in \mathbb{F} \tag{1}
\end{align}

then as the $0$ vector is unique we must have $0 \cdot x=0$.

My problem is that I'm not sure how we can conclude from $(1)$ that $0 \cdot x$ takes the role of the $0$ vector i.e. that $y+0 \cdot x=y \ \forall \ y \in V$. For equation $(1)$ to imply that $0 \cdot x$ was the $0$ vector, we would need $a \cdot x$ to map to every element of $V$ as $a$ varies, i.e. the map defined by $f:\mathbb{F} \rightarrow V, f(a)=a \cdot x$ is surjective. Is this in fact true?

Edit: For the record, I have found a proof that I am satisfied with, I just want to understand this proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the proof states that the result follows from uniqueness of zero, I would consider that a small mistake.  In fact, a stronger statement is needed, namely that if $u$ and $v$ are any two vectors with $u+v=u$, then we must have $v=0$.

But this is straightforward to prove, by subtraction, i.e. adding $-u$ to both sides:

$$
u+v = u\\
\implies (-u) + u + v = (-u) + u \\
\implies ((-u) + u) + v = ((-u) + u) \\
\implies 0 + v = 0 \\
\implies v = 0$$

Comment: This is the idea of the proof that I am satisfied with. The proof stated in the question was taken from Peter Lax's "Linear Algebra and its applications" which is why I assume it to be trustworthy, but I am not sure.

Comment: @CoolMathsGuy The proof as stated is wrong, for the reason you said, namely that not every vector can be written in the form $a\cdot x$.  I can cook up structures similar to vector spaces that have uniqueness of zero but where $0\cdot x \neq 0$.  My guess is that the author said "uniqueness of zero" but was really thinking of the stronger property that $+u$ is injective.  But this is still true, and a fundamental property of vector spaces generalizing uniqueness of zero, so I wouldn't call it a large error, but rather a small omission.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I'll accept your answer.